# If i want to calculate the length of a hanging chain given three heights, how do i iteratively find the correct tension factor?

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions, arc-length

I work in lighting. We rig bistro bulb strings a lot, and I'm trying to write a script that will calculate the **arc length** of cable we need to bring to different installs.

The givens I have to work with are:

- The *heights* of our rigging points from the ground (often different from each other)
- The *span* of the run (total horizontal distance)
- The *clearance*, which is the height of the lowest point of the line from the ground.

Formula for Catenary I'm using:

```
y(x) = a cosh(x/a) + c
```

Because we use the same materials for every install, physical factors such as linear weight and cross sectional area do not change. These constants determine the shape of the curve, and therefore its arc length, along with tension, which DOES change every installation, and scales linearly with *a*.

So far I have assumed the vertex lies at *x* = 0, which means the given clearance becomes *c*.

Because the vertex elevation also depends upon the physical properties of the chain, I believe defining an iterative value for tension should allow me to solve for an *a* that passes through all three defined points in space, but I can't figure out how to set this up. This is my question and what I need help with.

Once I have a process to determine a value for tension that gives me *a*, I should be able to solve the arc length formula for the newly defined catenary.

I've even found an online tool that calculates vertex position given only the difference between the two rigging points and the arc length, so I know that the reverse must be possible.

Ideally the solution will be generalized so I can compare proposed runs against the tension rating on our cables and know what is dimensionally possible within those physical constraints.

Comment: So you know the heights, but not the horizontal positions relative to the origin, of the rigging points?

Comment: Correct, but I do have the total distance between them. The other strategy I've tried is setting the origin to halfway so the horizontal positions are ±span/2 and adding a horizontal displacement variable to my function, but I hit a wall with that strategy as well.

Comment: The horizontal position of the origin shifts as tension changes, so perhaps the (x-b) strategy is better. I have found a proposal that uses newton's method for iteration, but it relies on symmetry of the rigging points and I can't figure out how to generalize that solution out for "any 2 rigging points"

Comment: Costello, Eric (2011) "Length of a Hanging Cable," Undergraduate Journal of Mathematical Modeling: One + Two: Vol. 4: Iss. 1, Article 4. DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.5038/2326-3652.4.1.4 Available at: https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/ujmm/vol4/iss1/4

Comment: [Here's the tool I found that calculates _a_ from length and rigging point coordinates](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2020/12/13/catenary-1/)

Comment: Are you willing to solve equation $(6)$ in https://www.alanzucconi.com/2020/12/13/catenary-1/ ? We can make pretty good *approximations*